# Change which microphone iOS 7 applications use?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, microphone

Here's the problem. I have an iPhone 5c and when I use the front facing camera to record video (whether using default camera app, Instagram, SnapChat) or when I use anything that uses the front microphone such as Siri or the speakerphone, the microphone does not pick up any sound.

The other two microphones work properly and what I am looking for is a tweak or function that disables the front microphone and uses the bottom or rear microphone to pickup sound.

If it comes down to it, I'll eventually buy a new replacement part but I would prefer to have a software tweak to keep my warranty intact and such.

If you could point me in the right direction of where I could go to request this or to even create this tweak myself, that would be greatly appreciated.

-

This is a relatively common issue it seems based on google searches. I know about the privacy settings, I've done the restores, I've done all of that and still no luck.

I am jailbroken on 7.0.4 iOS and I know quite a bit about the software and hardware.

Is there a .plist file for each application that uses the front microphone that I can change? Or a tweak I could create or use to disable the microphone and perhaps clone or mimic the other microphones but change the name it is used to lookup to enable what mic?

I don't know. Anything will help because right now all I have is the basic idea or concept.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault - just replace?